# Magnific Popup jquery installation

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm new to javascript and I want to use Magnific Popup (Ajax Type) on my website, but I'm not sure where to put the following code:

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax'
});
```

I have added the js and css files to my site and used the class in my "a href" tag below:

```
class="ajax-popup-link"
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty clearly documented on their site:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax_type

You specify the file path in the href attribute:

```
<a href="path-to-file.jpg" class="ajax-popup-link">click me</a>
```

Then in a document ready call you init magnific popup...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax'
    });
});
```

I don't think they specifically tell you to put it in a document ready call, but doing so at least ensures the elements exist before js attempts to add events and listeners.

Are you getting errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the document ready call into the <head> tag of my template file, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I'm doing this in Shopify and this is the code I added:<script>
  
  jQuery("document").ready(function (){ 

    
    $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax'
    });
      });
</script>